# Trouble with selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to duplicate the style of an existing menu using CSS.

The CMS platform that I'm using comes with given styling for the navgation. I added a new menu underneath it and am trying to make it look the same as the original. I added an ID "wpmenu" to the div that contains the navigation but the selectors don't select. I created a jsfiddle but the jsfiddle works!

It's really frustrating and I'm not sure where to turn. The html and CSS are here: http://jsfiddle.net/nRrKW/

The particular selector that seems to be failing is `#wpmenu li a`

Again, it works in jsfiddle but not on my website which is here: advance.trashswag.com.

I had expected to see the following CSS apply to the newly created UL nav within the "wpmenu" div:

```
#wpmenu li a {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        padding: 7px 12px;
        color: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 120%;
    }
```

But if I then inspect element on the site, the styling is not applied to those a elements.

Can anyone point out what I'm missing here?

Comment: which css file on the live site is this style in?

Comment: Viewed the source of you site's CSS files, but I couldn't find `"wpmenu li a"` using Firefox's search.

Comment: it's called style.css though I cannot see that in inspect element resources. It's in a theme "Gavin". My understanding of CMS structure is a little limited

Comment: At least in your fiddle, you have one too many `}` which is breaking it. You have two `}` at the end of your rules for `#wpmenu ul`. If you remove one, then it's finding the right elements for me.

Comment: There is no style.css being loaded as far as I can see.

Comment: @DougFirr @Paulie_D I found it in `theme_gavin.css`. It's with the selector `#wpmenu ul li a`.

Comment: the styling is in theme_gavin.css, `none}}#wpmenu a{` as you can see you have a second `}` this is causing a error in your css and not applying our styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have the `#wpmenu li a` style
also you have an invalid rule token here:

```
#wpmenu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}}
```

That might fix it!

Comment: Thanks so much! Nothing like a fresh pair of eyes

Comment: Nothing like _validating_ your code so you don’t even have to bother another pair of eyes …